# Extrair Metadata do Firebird via Delphi

Tags: delphi

Primeiramente pesquisei muito sobre  o assunto e não encontrei praticamente nada, somente a extração direto pelo IBExpert que não é o que eu preciso.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer a extração do Metadata do meu banco Firebird inteiro para atualizar outro banco Firebird que não possua todas as tabelas, triggers... Mas via delphi?

Comment: isql -extract -o metadata.sql banco.fdb

Comment: funciona com qualquer versão do Firebird?

Comment: A partir da versão 6

Comment: Reginaldo Rigo funcionou. Outra coisa você sabe se existe alguma forma de comparar dois bancos firebird e atualizar o que não esta com todas as tabelas, triggers...?

Comment: DBCompare http://clevercomponents.com/downloads/dbcomparer/dbcdownload.asp

Comment: Muito obrigado Reginaldo Rigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o componente `IBExtract` da paleta *IBExpress*

```
IBExtract1.ExtractObject(eoDatabase,'',[etDomain,etTable,etRole,etTrigger,etForeign,etIndex,etCheck]); 
TextoMetadata:= IBExtract1.Items.Text;
```

Sendo que você pode escolher apenas os objetos que você quer extrair, no último parâmetro

Comment: Estava quebrando a cabeça executando comandos no isql, mas agora sim ficou muito mais fácil. Obrigado Léo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o isql desse modo:

```
isql -extract -o metadata.sql banco.fdb
```